# Switching from Graphql to Grpc is very painful without using basic functionality like "a field is required or optional" and without using FieldMask

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I coming to grpc from GraphQL where I can select fields (and relative sub-fields) easily omitting or adding what I need.

This along with the "default value" way of protobuf makes the transition from GraphQL a little hard for me: it's me there to decide which field is mandatory, which is optional and what fields I want from the backend.

From what I've read I understand that this is possibly done in protobuf with [FieldMask](https://netflixtechblog.com/practical-api-design-at-netflix-part-1-using-protobuf-fieldmask-35cfdc606518).

Good, but if I add them in my proto files I don't have any typing guarantees in typescript, right? I tried packages like [`@bufbuild/connect-web`](https://github.com/bufbuild/connect-es) or [`timostamm/protobuf-ts`](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts).

Example:

```
message Player {
  google.protobuf.FieldMask field_mask = 1;
  string id = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp created_at = 3;
  string email = 4;
  string name = 5;
}
```

connect is generating:

```
export class Player extends Message<Player> {
  /**
   * @generated from field: google.protobuf.FieldMask field_mask = 1;
   */
  fieldMask?: FieldMask;

  // ...

  static readonly fields: FieldList = proto3.util.newFieldList(() => [
    { no: 1, name: "field_mask", kind: "message", T: FieldMask },
    { no: 2, name: "id", kind: "scalar", T: 9 /* ScalarType.STRING */ },
    { no: 3, name: "created_at", kind: "message", T: Timestamp },
    { no: 4, name: "email", kind: "scalar", T: 9 /* ScalarType.STRING */ },
    { no: 5, name: "name", kind: "scalar", T: 9 /* ScalarType.STRING */ },
  ]);
  
  // ...
}
```

Even if I put it on the request message is the same: no typings:

```
message PlayerByIdReq {
  string id = 1;
  google.protobuf.FieldMask field_mask = 2;
}
```

This is obviously error prone because the schema can change and the field_mask are simple strings in their daily usage:

```
const res = await client.playerById({
  id: '123',
  fieldMask: { paths: ['name', 'email'] }
});
```

Am I wrong in this? Is there something I'm missing?